# Angular 2 - page Refreshing issue

Tags: angular

In Angular 2 -  After routing in visual studio 15 (with .net core project) page do not load after refresh the page.

I define all the routing and their respective component,
but after refresh page is still blank.

Comment: try to debug from browser console.

Comment: http://localhost:50135/page
debugging not working and nothing error was show...

the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Try with `imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(myRoutes, {useHash: true})]`